# Populate Observable Collection from LINQ query results

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, mvvm

I'm just starting with WPF MVVM & I'm trying to populate a datagrid view by binding to an `ObservableCollection` in my view model.

I have used a simple LINQ query to select all from my table and populate my observable collection but my UI won't display the grid results, presumably because the XAML has to bind to a public property?

```
private void getTableResults()
{
    var query = from c in LDB.myTable
                select c;
    var results = query;

    ObservableCollection<myTable> MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<myTable>(results);
    OnPropertyChanged("MyCollection");
}
```

Here's my XAML binding:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
```

My `DataContext` is set and I've checked it binds against another hard-coded property. Where am I going wrong? I've put a breakpoint over the collection so know that it is being populated by the results. How can I expose a public `ObservableCollection` property which is populated from my LINQ results?

Thanks

Just to add, my data model is MyTable which is an Entity Framework 4.0 edmx.

Comment: Let me guess. You get an IEnumerable<> as a result?

Comment: `MyCollection` has to be a public property, not a local variable. Please make yourself familiar with the basics of [data binding in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the data context of your view is your viewmodel, then yes - your xaml binding should be to a public property of your viewmodel.
So declare your 'MyCollection' property as a property of the viewmodel (not a local property of your getTbaleResults method).

```
private ObservableCollection<myTable> _myCollection;
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the myTable collection.
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<myTable> MyCollection
{
    get { return _myCollection; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _myCollection) return;
        _myCollection= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyCollection);
    }
}
```

(Note this is using Prism so the lambda on RaisePropertyChanged, but other frameworks have similar implementations).

Comment: Ok, I understand this where you are exposing a public Observable Collection property but then how do I populate the collection from the LINQ query?

Comment: @Hardgraf Very simply. Assign `MyCollection = ...` just as you did before, but *without* declaring it as a local variable. And remove the `OnPropertyChanged` call, as that is now in the property setter.

Comment: Yeah I've tried to do that. MyCollection = results; but the compiler can't 'Implicitly convert Iqueryable to ObservableCollection...

Comment: @Hardgraf Which part of "as you did before" is so hard to understand? Write `MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<myTable>(results);`.